# Exchange of messages in a chat room without saving them in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, message, privacy

I am making an anonymous chat room in PHP, and I need to find a way of making/receiving messages without saving them in the database. I was thinking of using Comet, but that's not the most efficient/best way.

What is the way of exchanging information between logged in users without actually saving them in the database?

Comment: If you can use MySQL, maybe set up the [MEMORY database engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)? You'll need to recreate your tables every time the database server is (re)started.

Comment: You can use Memcache? But when your server restart you loose all messages.

Comment: @ChoiZ: I expect that's the idea!

Comment: You might want to monitor memory usage too.

Comment: @halfer :), so memcache, Mysql or mongodb seems to be a good solution to do that.

Comment: The thing is, I want to make it like completely anonymous. I am a member of a forum, and I want to keep absolutely no record of the messages, and if I store them in cache, it is still possible to get hold of them. Is it possible to "Push" these sent messages to the users in the room and then completely destruct the message?

Comment: Once they are delivered, you can then delete them from the storage system. You _have_ to hang onto them for a bit, since you don't know whether they can be delivered until you've tried. I wrote a HOWTO for an AJAX chat facility a few days ago, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22870255/472495). If you plan to use AJAX, hanging onto messages for a while is necessary. It may be different for push/comet technology though.

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying. So maybe have it available for 10 seconds, so you make sure that everyone in the room had the chance to fetch the message, and then just erase it out of there with maybe a cron job or another like service?

Comment: If you have many participants in a room _and_ you are using AJAX, you'll need to hang onto the message until it has gone to everyone (or you could delete it after ten seconds and risk it not going to everyone). For comet it is a bit better, since you can push from the server and delete straight away. Neither case guarantees delivery, unless you have a hashing and redelivery strategy (but that requires storage).

Comment: You can also use WebRTC, that saves you the php. http://blog.printf.net/articles/2013/05/17/webrtc-without-a-signaling-server/

Comment: Hmm, I think another way would be to encrypt the messages so no one without the keys would be able to decrypt it. Thanks guys!

Comment: It seems to me like you might need to implement encryption at rest if you are concerned about access to messages. I don't think it is reasonable to think you can set up a system like this without storing the messages in some manner.

Comment: And wrap it in SSL, for all the good that'll do these days... `;-)`

Comment: (Bear in mind this problem may already have been solved, so do a thorough search too).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet is to use a messaging queue mechanism such as ZeroMQ. You would need to implement each client to be a subscriber to your message queue. When a client wants to send a message to the others, it publishes a message to the server which then, in turn, broadcasts it to the rest of the clients that shall receive it. You can also do it in the same way by using a P2P model but it is probably much more complicated to implement.